# Count Number of Cells with Dates that are in a Given Month

Tags: excel, date, countif

I've got several dates in column B3:B62 that appear as mm/dd/yyyy

in cell n4 i want return all the total number of cells that have dates that fall in the month of january

i've tried  =COUNTIF(B3:B62;=>"2/1/2014")

this only returns a value error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
=COUNTIFS(B3:B62, ">=1/1/2014", B3:B62, "<2/1/2014")
```

Microsoft Documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed)

Comment: thanks i really appreciate it. i tried this formula but it only shows zero in n4 after i've tried it.

Comment: make sure that the data in column B is formatted as a date and not as text.

Comment: When you double click on n4 which has the above formula, does it show your desired rows (B3:B62) selected?

Comment: Please update the question with few dates in B3:B62 that you think should match the criteria

Comment: How did you check whether the dates were text or not? Once text-formatted you can't just change to numbers by changing the format - what do you get with the formula =ISNUMBER(B3)? If B3 is a true date you should get **TRUE**

Comment: it returns FALSE when use ISNUMBER(B3)

Comment: @user3509034, that is your problem. You need to convert it to date. One way is to copy the column else where like notepad, delete from excel, and paste it back using 'Text to Columns' and make sure you select column data format as Date MDY.

Comment: This is exactly what my problem was. I followed these steps to convert the column dates into "true" dates: •Select the range of dates in question •Goto Data>Text to Columns •Click Next twice
•In step 3 of the wizard under Column data format select Date and from the drop down select the format that matches the format of the entries. If 02/08/12 is supposed to be in m/d/y format select MDY from the drop down. If 02/08/12 is supposed to be in day/month/year format then select DMY from the drop down. After these steps, The first formula worked =COUNTIFS(B3:B62, ">=1/1/2014", B3:B62, "<2/1/2014")

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B62;">=1/1/2014")-COUNTIF(B3:B62;">1/2/2014")
```

and, if that does not work (!) switching `"1/2/2014"` to `"2/1/2014"`.

Comment: thanks. excel keeps prompting me that the formula contains an error :-(

Comment: excel wont even let me exaluate it - i just get the error

Comment: i am sorry but i am an idiot - and i do not even know how to translate COUNTIF/S. i guess you mean make sure that the function bar shows "COUNTIFS"? if so, i've done that & it's still not working :-(

Comment: I assume that the semi-colon separators might be the problem - in UK and US `commas` are normally used as separators, where are you?